# How to order a query by a field that is not being selected

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am a nwbie to SQL queries and stored procedures and I am trying to order a query where there is 3 inner joins but I get this error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Here is the code of query that I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    P.ProductId,
    PID.IndexId
FROM
    Products AS P
INNER JOIN 
    #ProductIds AS PID ON P.ProductId = PID.ProductId
INNER JOIN 
    ProductStores AS PS ON P.ProductId = PS.ProductId
ORDER BY 
    CASE PS.Status 
       WHEN 1 THEN 1 
       ELSE 2 
    END 
    OFFSET (@PageIndex * @PageSize) ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT (@PageSize) ROWS ONLY;
```

When I remove the distinct keyword, the rows are being repeated many times

Comment: Often when you get repeating rows it is an indication that the join predicates are not correct. The error message can't be more clear though.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the JOIN; the error is actually telling you the problem. You're trying to order your data by the expression `CASE PS.Status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END` however, that expression is **not** in your `SELECT`. With `DISTINCT` you can only order your dataset by rows that appear in the `SELECT`.

Comment: I am guessing you may be able to use group by with max & case here and then order by the calculated column. But without sample data it's impossible to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it ...

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    P.ProductId, 
    PID.IndexId, 
    (CASE tb.Status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS Status
FROM Products AS P 
    INNER JOIN #ProductIds AS PID ON P.ProductId = PID.ProductId 
    INNER JOIN ProductStores AS PS ON P.ProductId = PS.ProductId ) as tb
ORDER BY tb.Status OFFSET (@PageIndex * @PageSize) ROWS FETCH NEXT (@PageSize) ROWS ONLY;
```

Because The order by statement execute after select statement. And when distinct two column may be include difference status. This mean that thing that two row. 1st row 1 (ProductId), 2 (IndexId), 1 (Status) and 2nd row 1 (ProductId), 2(IndexId), 2(Status). When you get the first distinct two column. It return only 1 row but which status? But you add status column then it know status column individually.

Comment: Code only answers are often considered low quality because they don't explain why the original code was incorrect.

Comment: Because The order by statement execute after select statement. And when distinct two column may be include difference status. This mean that thing that two row. 1st row 1 (ProductId), 2 (IndexId), 1 (Status) and 2nd row 1 (ProductId), 2(IndexId), 2(Status). When you get the first distinct two column. It return only 1 row but which status? But you add status column then it know status column individually.

Answer (score 1):

Your results are only interested in showing fields that come from `Products` and `#ProductIds` - (`ProductId` and `IndexId`) - however you are then joining a third table which you are attempting to order by (`ProductStores`).

If you had a `ProductId` which had 100 `ProductStores` associated with it then the `DISTINCT` would show you that *one* `ProductId` *regardless* of the `ProductStores.Status` field.

It may be better to ask you - what answer are you wanting?

I'm guessing you are wanting to list Products which have an `Status = 1` associated with them first. However, it looks like there's nothing to stop a Product being associated with *both* a `Status = 1` store and a `Status = 0` store. This is why it's not possible for SQL to give you answers in this case - where you are wanting one row per Product.

To order by the status you would need to output it. However then, you will get a row for every combination of Product, Index, Status.

@mimamiq's answer could probably work without the outer `SELECT`...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    P.ProductId, 
    PID.IndexId, 
    PS.Status
FROM Products AS P 
    INNER JOIN #ProductIds AS PID ON P.ProductId = PID.ProductId 
    INNER JOIN ProductStores AS PS ON P.ProductId = PS.ProductId
ORDER BY 
    CASE tb.Status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
OFFSET (@PageIndex * @PageSize) ROWS FETCH NEXT (@PageSize) ROWS ONLY;
```

**But note** - if you are wanting *one row per product/productid combination* - then this won't work (unless there are other constraints on your database which we don't know about).